# Jquery active class trouble

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tGW3D/2/)

```
 $('li').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

All is great but I need another thing. I need that class removes when i click `li` with active class again.

Answer (score 2):

So, replace this line:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

With this:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

See: [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass('active');
 });
```